Field Service Mobile - LWC issue, record not being created on rare occassion
We have an LWC in a Field Service Mobile (FSM) app that creates a Case record via the createRecord LDS method. Once the promise returns its result, a 2nd record 'Case Details' is created, which looks up to Case.
On rare occasion (~5%), the Case Detail record is not being created. We have narrowed it down to the LWC rather than the FSM's sync, because there are no sync errors.
Due to various challenges and constraints, we are struggling to find the root cause. There are current challenges with extracting the device debug logs that the FSM offers. To work around that, additional error logging has been added to the LWC to try and capture the issue by creating the log as a new record ApplicationLog. We have deployed it this week, and are waiting for logging information to come through.
While waiting for that - I am sharing the current LWC code below (refactored for sharing) to see if other Field Service Mobile experts out there can see improvements. For example - if there's a better way to perform the sequential createRecord calls.
  handleCreate() {
        //Prepare CASE record to create
        let subject = this.caseType+ ' - ' + this.subType + ' - ' + this.category;
        try {
            const fields = {};
            fields[RECORDTYPEID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.caseRecordTypeId;
            fields[STATUS_FIELD.fieldApiName] = "Open";
            fields[SUBJECT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = subject.substring(0,254);
            const caseRecord = {apiName : CASE_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields : fields};

            this.newCaseRecordStringify = JSON.stringify(caseRecord);
            console.log('*** caseRecord *** ' + this.newCaseRecordStringify);

            createRecord(caseRecord)
            .then(newCaseRecord => {
                console.log('*** Successfully created Case record *** ');
                try {
                    //Prepare CASE_EXT record to create
                    const caseDetailFields = {};
                    caseDetailFields[RECORDTYPEID_CASEDETAIL_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.caseDetailRecordTypeId;
                    caseDetailFields[CASE_CASEDETAIL_FIELD.fieldApiName] =  newCaseRecord.id;
                    const caseDetailRecord = {apiName : CASEDETAIL_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields : caseDetailFields};
                    this.newCaseDetailRecordStringify = JSON.stringify(caseDetailRecord);

                    console.log('*** caseDetailRecord *** ' + this.newCaseDetailRecordStringify );
                    //throw new Error("test error message"); // For testing error handling including ApplicationLog generation

                    createRecord(caseDetailRecord)
                    .then(newCaseDetailRecord => {
                        console.log('*** Successfully created Case Extension record *** ');
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            this.showForm = false;
                            this.showReview = false;
                            this.showSubmitted = true;
                        }, 2000);
                    })
                } catch (error) {
                    let toastOptions = {
                        title: 'Error creating Case Detail record',
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: 'error',
                        mode: 'sticky',
                    };
                    let appLogValues = {
                        errmsg: 'Error creating Case Extension record from newCase LWC. ' + error.message,
                        errtype: 'Field Service Mobile - custom LWC error',
                        sourceclass: 'LWC.newCase.js',
                        sourcefunc: 'handleCreate',
                        loglevel: 'ERROR',
                        referenceid: 'N/A',
                        stacktrace: 'Case Ext values: ' + this.newCaseRecordStringify,
                    };
        
                    this.handleError('*** error in createCaseDetailRecord *** ' + error.message, 'Case Ext values: ' + this.newCaseRecordStringify, toastOptions, appLogValues);
                }
            })
        } catch (error) {
            let toastOptions = {
                title: 'Error creating Case record',
                message: error.message,
                variant: 'error',
                mode: 'sticky',
            };
            let appLogValues = {
                errmsg: 'Error creating Case record from newCase LWC. ' + error.message,
                errtype: 'Field Service Mobile - custom LWC error',
                sourceclass: 'LWC.newCase.js',
                sourcefunc: 'handleCreate',
                loglevel: 'ERROR',
                referenceid: 'N/A',
                stacktrace: 'Case values: ' + this.newCaseRecordStringify,
            };
            this.handleError('*** error in createCaseRecord *** ' + error.message, 'Case values: ' + this.newCaseRecordStringify, toastOptions, appLogValues);
        }
    }

    handleError(err, stack, toastOptions, appLogValues) {
        try {
            this.logToConsole(err, stack);
            this.createApplicationLog(appLogValues);
            this.getToastEvent(toastOptions);

        } catch (ex) {
            console.error(ex);
            console.error(err);
            console.error(stack);
        }
    }


    getToastEvent(options) {
        const opts = options || {};
        return new ShowToastEvent({
            title: opts.title || "An error has occurred",
            message: opts.message || this.message,
            variant: opts.variant || "error",
            messageData: opts.messageData,
            mode: opts.mode || "dismissible"
        });
    }
    
    logToConsole(err,stack) {
        //Print the system error message
        console.error(err);
        //Print the stack message if any
        if (this.stack !== undefined) {
            console.log(stack);
        }
    }

    createApplicationLog(appLogValues) {
        try {
            //Prepare APPLICATION LOG record to create
            const appLogFields = {};
            appLogFields[ERRMSG_APPLOG_FIELD.fieldApiName] = appLogValues.errmsg;
            appLogFields[ERRTYPE_APPLOG_FIELD.fieldApiName] = appLogValues.errtype;
            appLogFields[SOURCECLASS_APPLOG_FIELD.fieldApiName] = appLogValues.sourceclass;
            appLogFields[SOURCEFUNC_APPLOG_FIELD.fieldApiName] = appLogValues.sourcefunc;
            appLogFields[LOGLVL_APPLOG_FIELD.fieldApiName] = appLogValues.loglevel;
            appLogFields[REFID_APPLOG_FIELD.fieldApiName] = appLogValues.referenceid;
            appLogFields[STACKTRACE_APPLOG_FIELD.fieldApiName] = appLogValues.stacktrace;
            const appLogRecord = {apiName : APPLOG_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields : appLogFields};
            console.log('*** appLogRecord *** ' + JSON.stringify(appLogRecord));
            createRecord(appLogRecord)
            .then(newAppLogRecord => {
                console.log('*** Successfully created Application Log record *** ');
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('*** Try/Catch error in createApplicationLog *** ' + error);
        }

    }


From what I can tell, the code tries (where it fires a toast "Error creating Case Detail record") to catch an asynchronous error (caused by createRecord(caseDetailRecord)). This can't work.
Assume this:
checkErrorHandling() {
    try {
        doSomething()
        .then(() => {
        })
        //.catch(() => {
        //   console.log('In inner catch');
        //});
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('In outer catch');
    }
    console.log('After all');
}

The first thing that happens here is: "After all" is printed to the console. Afterwards, if the asynchronous doSomething() fails, - it's too late for the outer catch block.
If the inner catch block is uncommented, all is well: If doSomething() fails, - "In inner catch" will be printed to the console and no error reaches the outside world.
try/catch are better not mixed with asynchronous method calls, which expect then/catch.
I think I'm not the only one, who would recommend to use async/await. It allows the use of conventional try/catch and is much more readable.
